# I have a simple program to get a text from a specific url but it keeps showing Errno 11001

Tags: python, sockets

This is my program, it is generally copied from a tutorial, but it is not working, I don't know why.
    import socket

```
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/intro-short.txt', 80))
mysock.send('GET http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/intro-short.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data)<1):
        break
    print(data)

mysock.close()
```

THis is the mistake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\python\eclipse\ex1\socketexp.py", line 4, in <module>
    mysock.connect(('http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/intro-short.txt', 80))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 1):

A socket connects to a host, not a url.  So rather than

> mysock.connect(('http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/intro-short.txt',
>   80))

do

> mysock.connect(('www.pythonlearn.com', 80))

Then the connection should work as you expect.